# Memory Leak UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

As an extension to the question posted here: [Loading UICollectionView data source dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20607705/loading-uicollectionview-data-source-dynamically)

My `UICollectionView` needs to be reloaded with new data every time. So, the data source is changed and `[myCollectionView reloadData]` is called every time to refresh the data. Its been working for me. But the problem is with the memory. The cells already loaded in `myCollectionView` object don't seem to be released. So, every time, the view is refreshed, I seen an increase in the memory, though the number of cells are reduced for every refresh. When I release the collection view(Did it to see if the cells are released), I see the dealloc function of the cell is called for each occurrence of cell.  Do I need to call any function to clear the memory of the cells that are appended to my collection view? Am I missing something significant here? Please advise.

Comment: Presumably you're using dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier, so you wouldn't expect to see them being released on reloadData. It doesn't explain the increase in memory each time though.

Comment: How do you know that the increase in memory is due to increased number of cells? maybe it's something with your data? 
Anyway, you don't need to release memory of the cells, the collection view does it. If you add some views to the cells, or you do some code inside your cells, of course you need to make sure you are not leaking there.

Comment: @AviTsadok you are right, I missed to remove one of the subviews added to the cell. After I found this, everything seems to be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a memory leak inside the UICollectionViewcell dealloc. Not removing one of the subviews added to the cell. After removing from superview, seems to be fine.